# Non-conformable arguments error in root finding function

Tags: python, r, function, syntax-error

I am trying to solve for x in:

[image]

Two implementations in R:

```
H <- diag(2)  # 2-dimensional diagonal matrix with ones on the diagonal
uniroot.all(function(x, y, H) {c(t(x)) %*% solve(H) %*% c(x) - y}, y=y, H=H, lower=0, upper=10) 
uniroot.all(function(x, y, H) {t(x) %*% solve(H) %*% x - y}, y=y, H=H, lower=0, upper=10)
```

However, both give the same non-conformable arguments error:

```
Error in c(t(x)) %*% solve(H) : non-conformable arguments
Error in t(x) %*% solve(H) : non-conformable arguments
```

I understand the error but perhaps someone could shed some light how to solve for x in the equation above because I do not arrive at a solution (R or Python is fine)

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Can you give an example that satisfies the equation above?

Comment: @Onyambu What I am actually trying to achieve is finding the cutoff value for the ellipsoid defining the highest density region of an N(0,H) random variable such as [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/127486/122737)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there will be many values that satisfy the condition. eg take an example where H is identity matrix and y is for example 5, then x can be c(1,2) or (2,1) or (1.656615, 1.501874) or (2.2184971, 0.2797686) etc etc.. So all this form an elipse at which the sol is 5:

thus we can do:

```
 optim(c(0,1.9),function(x,H,y)abs(c(crossprod(x,solve(H,x)))-y),H=diag(2),y=5)
```

You can test the solutions given from the above code and you will see that they actually give 5. choose any starting values:

```
s=function(w,u)optim(c(w,u),function(x,H,y)abs(c(crossprod(x,solve(H,x)))-y),H=diag(2),y=5)$par
a=1:4
r=t(mapply(s,a,rep(a,each=length(a))))
cbind(r,rowSums(r^2))
           [,1]      [,2] [,3]
 [1,] 1.2216786 1.8728325    5
 [2,] 2.0000000 1.0000000    5
 [3,] 1.1964828 1.8890286    5
 [4,] 0.2209853 2.2251215    5
 [5,] 1.0000000 2.0000000    5
 [6,] 1.6566155 1.5018739    5
 [7,] 0.1675176 2.2297843    5
 [8,] 1.2257806 1.8701503    5
 [9,] 1.8890286 1.1964828    5
[10,] 2.2297843 0.1675176    5
[11,] 1.6043461 1.5575857    5
[12,] 1.2658540 1.8432617    5
[13,] 2.2251215 0.2209853    5
[14,] 1.8701503 1.2257806    5
[15,] 1.8432617 1.2658540    5
[16,] 1.6636298 1.4941003    5
```

You see that all of them give you 5.

Comment: Thank you @Onyambu for clarification. The fact there are multiple solutions that satisfy the condition makes sense given that the equation describes an ellipsoid. But is it safe to say that there are in principle an infinite number of solutions? Thanks again.

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of using abs in the function. I understand it will compute the absolute value of c(crossprod(x,solve(H,x)))-y. But why is it used?

Comment: Just to ensure the function does not produce a value less than zero. We are minimizing the distance between the two values. to minimize, then we should have a very small value as possible. If you do not use abs, you will get negative values, this will never solve since it will still continue to minimize the gradient and function value obtaining very big negative values.. but our aim is to obtain values close to zero

Comment: One final question after reading up on the minimization algorithm used by the function optim. I believe the default is "Nelder-Mead" but I believe "L-BFGS-B" might be a bit faster when the jacobian/hessian is provided. The reason I would care about this is that, as part of further analysis, I will retrieve many solutions that satisfy the equation for rather large number of distinct positive definite matrices H (about 500). I believe the minimization problem is one of unconstrained convex optimization and "L-BFGS-B" would be suitable to obtain satisfiable solutions. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Paul I mostly use BFGS.